# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'accumulate'

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

After I import itertools, i run itertools.accumulate() on the code below and i get an error saying -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Equal_Stacks.py", line 36, in <module>
    result = equalStacks(h1 , h2 , h3)
  File "Equal_Stacks.py", line 8, in equalStacks
    h11 = itertools.accumulate(h1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'accumulate'
```

But when i run the itertools.accumulate() function in the interpretor it works just fine.

```
import sys
import itertools

def equalStacks(h1 , h2 , h3):
    h11 = itertools.accumulate(h1)

    h22 = itertools.accumulate(h2)

    h33 = itertools.accumulate(h3)

    equal = False
    while not equal:
        if h11[-1] == h22[-1] == h33[-1]:
            equal = True
            break
        else:
            if h11[-1] > h22[-1] and h11[-1] > h33[-1] and len(h11) != 0:
                h11.pop()
            elif h22[-1] > h11[-1] and h22[-1] > h33[-1] and len(h22) != 0:
                h22.pop()
            elif h33[-1] > h11[-1] and h33[-1] > h22[-1] and len(h33) != 0:
                h33.pop()

    return str(h11[-1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n1 , n2 , n3 = map( int , sys.stdin.readline().strip().split() )

    h1 = list( map( int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split() ) )
    h2 = list( map( int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split() ) )
    h3 = list( map( int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split() ) )

    result = equalStacks(h1 , h2 , h3)

    _ = sys.stdout.write( result + '\n')
```

Comment: Can you specify the Inputs please?

Comment: 5 3 4,3 2 1 1 1,4 3 2,1 1 4 1. The commas mean newline/enter key. Its basically a Equal Stacks problem on Hackerrank.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code on my editor and first i got this, which doesn't seem right:

```
h11: Iterator
Value 'h11' is unsubscriptablepylint(unsubscriptable-object)
```

Then i tried to execute your code with the input and i got an error similar to yours, but it said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Chechu/Desktop/s.py", line 33, in <module>
    result = equalStacks(h1 , h2 , h3)
  File "c:/Users/Chechu/Desktop/s.py", line 13, in equalStacks
    if h11[-1] == h22[-1] == h33[-1]:
TypeError: 'itertools.accumulate' object is not subscriptable
```

As you can see the lines of accumulate work just fine (you can also [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)).

I think that you are misunderstanding what an iterator is as you cannot access elements from it. You have to do a casting to list to that iterators. Your code only needs:

```
h11 = list(itertools.accumulate(h1))

h22 = list(itertools.accumulate(h2))

h33 = list(itertools.accumulate(h3))
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you're using the correct python version. There's a difference between python and python3.

*python* calls python 2.*, while *python3* calls python 3.*. The accumulate module is only available in python3